# Uncomfortable vs discomforted vs discomfortable vs uncomforted

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

“Did you feel _____ after the surgery?”

In the above sentence, should ‘uncomfortable’, ‘discomforted’, ‘discomfortable’, or ‘uncomforted’ be used?

If so, what is the difference between the four options?

Comment: Uncomfortable is more common than the other words I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have to say ***uncomfortable*** is the correct word. ***Uncomfortable*** means "feeling discomfort." It is very common for patients to feel uncomfortable after a surgery.

***Discomfortable*** is not a real word. **Note: I have since been informed that it IS a word. See link in comment below. It's not a word I've ever heard here in the U.S. -- could be more commonly used in a different dialect.

***Did you feel discomforted?*** means ***did someone make you feel uneasy?*** This is obviously not the intent of the sentence.

***Uncomforted*** refers to the condition of feeling "neglected" or "unconsoled." This refers to someone not getting attention or care from other people. Again, the intent of the question is to ask about physical discomfort, not about mental or spiritual neglect.

Comment: [Discomfortable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discomfortable) is a valid word

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your second question first:

> what is the difference between the four options?

There is a subtle difference in the general use of the two words when used for a person

[Uncomfortable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uncomfortable) is an adjective used to ***describe the state*** of a person in which he is feeling uneasy or discomfit

[Discomfortable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discomfortable) is an adjective used to ***describe the person*** who is in a state of (mental or physical) discomfort or uneasiness. Having said that, it is also an obsolete term used [in place of uncomfortable](https://wikidiff.com/discomfortable/uncomfortable).

Discomforted is used as a verb in past tense when something made you feel uneasy and Uncomforted simply means not comforted as explained by Ringo in his [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/151100/65060)

As far as the first question is concerned:

> In the above sentence, should ‘uncomfortable’, ‘discomforted’,
>   ‘discomfortable’, or ‘uncomforted’ be used?

Uncomfortable is the correct answer as you are looking for an adjective to describe the person's state after the surgery.